# Getting Random values from Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

How to fetch RANDOM User_names.

```
SELECT a.mod_name, u.user_name, a.id from type a, users u 
WHERE a.id=u.mod_type
ORDER BY mod_type Desc ";
```

Comment: how many username do you want from a single select?

Comment: You want one random user name for each type?

Comment: All usernames present in users table. @ariefbayu

Comment: Random user name available in users table for each type. @Jack

Comment: let me wrap: you want to show ALL type with only one random username for each type?

Comment: Answered by LoVeSmItH @ariefbayu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about

**EDIT:**

```
select a.mod_name, u.user_name, a.id from type a, users u where a.id=u.mod_type 
order by mod_type DESC, rand();
```

?

Comment: @AvinVarghese, it will obviously fetch all mod types as you dont have any condition to filter out mod types in your query. Try reversing the order by part to, `order by mod_type DESC, rand() `

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ORDER BY RAND()` for that:

```
SELECT a.mod_name, u.user_name, a.id
FROM type a, users u
WHERE a.id=u.mod_type
ORDER BY RAND()
```

Comment: Want **order by mod_type Desc** as it.@ariefbayu

Comment: Thank You ariefbayu for your effort. @ariefbayu

Answer (score 2):

Mysql supports `RAND()` function

```
 select a.mod_name, u.user_name, a.id from type a,
 users u where a.id=u.mod_type
 order by RAND(),mod_type Desc ";
```

Comment: Want **order by mod_type Desc** as it.@akhilraj-n-s

Comment: Thank You Akhilraj for your effort. @Akhilraj N S